# Background Worker worker_spi Example PostgreSQL

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to run the demo background worker example present in PostgreSQL documentation. I downloaded it from: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/src/test/modules/worker_spi

I am able to compile the code and the following files are created:
"worker_spi.o" and "worker_spi.so"

I then ran worker_spi--1.0.sql with:- \i worker_spi--1.0.sql.
Finally, after connecting to the database, I created an extension as specified in SQL file. But, I don't think it is working. Do I need to put this ".so" file in some other directory? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I will not follow links within links. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried. And, "I don't think it is working" does not adequately describe the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am only trying to run the demo example given. They have created a schema and a table initially. And then through a background worker they are deleting and updating the rows from the table. Upon the initial creation of table, a log message is also being printed.

Comment: I am not able to see any schema or table once I run the SQL script. Also, what is the default log file location of postgreSQL?

Comment: You need to run make install, and I don't know if this will play nice with a system Postgres (one not built from your code checkout). And you probably shouldn't be running worker_spi by hand, but instead doing CREATE EXTENSION.

Comment: Thanks. But do I need to copy worker_spi.so to some other directory of postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the .so file needs to be installed into the PKGLIBDIR.

You can find out what the PKGLIBDIR is by running "pg_config".  For example, on an Ubuntu system with PostgreSQL 9.4, pg_config will return:

PKGLIBDIR = /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib

Further, the worker_spi--1.0.sql should be installed into SHAREDIR/extension.  On an Ubuntu system with PostgreSQL 9.4, the SHAREDIR returned from pg_config is:

SHAREDIR = /usr/share/postgresql/9.4

And the directory to install the worker_spi--1.0.sql is:

/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension

Once the worker_spi--1.0.sql and worker_spi.so files are installed into the correct locations, you should be able to execute:

CREATE EXTENSION worker_spi;

from any database and have the extension be installed.

Using "\i worker_spi--1.0.sql" does not install it as an extension but rather as a set of independent objects.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes much more sense now. 
I copied the respective files to the following locations: 

"/usr/pgsql-9.4/share/extension"
and

"/usr/pgsql-9.4/lib"

I then restarted the postgres server. Finally, when I am trying to create the required extension, it is not being created. Is there still something else that I need to do?

Comment: There is another file called: worker_spi.control. Do I need to put it some other directory?

Comment: What error message are you seeing when you try to create the extension?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am able to create an extension now. Also the required background worker. One step which I was missing is to add the database name of this background worker in my config file. So in postgresql.conf:
worker_spi.database = ‘databasename’ has to be added.